# How to restore a source file for winHelp (.HLP)

Tags: vb6, winhelp

I have a VB 6 application with a Help HLP file. The source file that was used for creating the HLP file is lost.

Is there a way to restore the source file so that I could edit it and recompile the new Help file?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a WinHelp decompiler on Google. It converts the .HLP file back to it's RTF source that you can then edit using a text editor or MS Word. You can find a .HLP compiler on the Microsoft website.

Or you can purchase something like [Help and Manual](http://www.helpandmanual.com), which includes a .HLP decompiler, an editor for help text, and can compile WinHelp and HTML Help, as well as produce PDF manuals, all from the same source.